Ubuntu does not find installed AppImage application to open link from browser
I'm trying to open a 3D model in Cura 5.7.0 from browser (Firefox 124.0.1).
For example, from this page, clicking the "C" on the right:

It says it does not find any suitable application:

and clicking on "Find in software" leads to a second error message:

But I downloaded Cura 5.7.0 as AppImage on my system and it runs fine. I also installed it using the AppImageLauncher.
How can I tell the system to open those links with the installed software Cura?
UPDATE
Following the hint of user Archisman Panigrahi I created the following desktop file:
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/opt/appimages/UltiMaker-Cura-5.7.0-linux-X64_c0f23abd0d30d731922faa3fbf52c6dc.AppImage %f
Name=UltiMaker Cura 5.7.0 Appimage
Terminal=false
Type=Application

Now in the activity menu I can see two Cura entries: the one I created and the one already created by AppImageLauncher.
Now I can select my "Cura 3.7.0 AppImage" application from the "Open with" dialog if I try to open a file on my drive (i.e. right click > Open with).
But the behavior related to the link in the browser is exactly the same described above.

You can manually add the path of the appimage in Open With. Alternatively, create a desktop file (https://blog.robertelder.org/custom-open-with-program-ubuntu/) and place it in .local/share/applications in your home folder

@ArchismanPanigrahi where can I "manually add the path of the appimage in Open With"? I don't see any input field nor browse buttons in that dialog

Perhaps I have that option because I am using Cinnamon desktop (not the default GNOME). Try creating a desktop file instead

@ArchismanPanigrahi done. Question updated with the result!
